# Embedded Swing in SWT, Graphical Errors

Tags: java, swing, swt, eclipse-rcp

i write a Eclipse Plugin with JTrees Embedded via SWT_AWT Bridge.

```
Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.NO_BACKGROUND | SWT.EMBEDDED);
java.awt.Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
```

It works well.
But when i select an Item its cause graphical problems.
[image]

When i clicked beside the JTree the "Cheese" effect disappears.

The same JTree CellRenderer and JTree CellEditor works fine 
while Running in a JFrame, only the Embedded part causes the errors.

Need Help!

Konobi

Comment: Why not use a JFace `TreeViewer`?

Comment: Its a MultiPartEditor with 3 JTrees on each Tap with multiple Taps. And I dont know how I write a TreeViewer with custom Icons, Checkboxs and Radiobuttons.

Comment: I Think its a repaint() problem. When i clicked the checkBox only onPressed its generates the error or when i clicked the Label.

Comment: I used Transparenty Colors.... problem solves without transparency

Comment: Then go ahead and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used

```
setBackground(0, 255, 0, 150) // graphical errors
```

whereas

```
setBackground(0, 255, 0) // no errors
```

results in no errors.